# Is it Possible to Create a git Repository from an SVN Log File?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, restore

I would love to import an old university project to github. The version control was handled SVN, and my access to the server is long gone.

All I have is the latest up-to-date copy of the files, along with a file containing the output of `svn log`. To me this seems like enough data to somehow restore the entire history of the repository. Does anyone know if there is some way of doing this? Either by re-creating a SVN repo, or by converting directly to git.

I used TortoiseSVN on the local working copy if that helps (still has the .svn folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible, since SVN is centralized, meaning the actual content of the older versions are on a SVN server.

This differs from a decentralized VCS like git, where *all* the version contents are stored within the `.git` folder.

You can create a git repo with the latest versions of those file, and go from there.

Comment: That makes sense. I should have thought about the lack of content itself... Thanks.